# I have 4 radio buttons. I want that my last selected radio button get selected everytime

Tags: android

I have 4 radio buttons. I want that my last selected radio button get selected every time. till i don't change it. (When i re-open my app it is found already selected)

Comment: please show the HTML...dont keep us guessing

Comment: share your code with question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community. If you have a question about something very specific, you should include your code. If you have not tried to implement something, I strongly recommend you to search about your issue more. It seems like what you want to do is very common. (hint: search for `SharedPreference`)

Comment: save that button state in `shared preferences` then when you open app set its state according to `shared preferences saved state` simple.

Comment: `android:checked="true"`                                                                                                                                 add this line to your last (fourth) radio button. and it will make every time the last one selected. If any other radio button has this line, remove it from others.                                                                                                                          I am answering in context of android, because you have added tag of android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:checked="true"` to keep whichever radiobutton u want to be checked by default. In this case the second button will be checked by default.

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pirates"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ninjas"
    android:checked="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
```